# if else boolean/checkbox on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, boolean

I have a blog app. Every post needs to be **checked "Published"** first, before it appears on the front page. I need a checkbox on the form.

In django I can achieve this with:

#### models.py

```
...
published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
...
```

#### views.py

```
...
posts =  Post.objects.filter(published=True)
```

How I can achieve this in Rails?

---------- UPDATE ---------

**[SOLVED]**

Step-by-Step -

Add new migration :

```
rails g migration add_published_to_posts published:boolean
```

On migration file, set published default to `False`

```
class AddPublishedToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :published, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

Also update the model `Post.rb` :

```
# app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
  scope :unpublished, -> { where(published: false) }
end
```

And in the posts controller :

```
 def index
   @posts = Post.where(published: true)
 end
```

Add `:published` permit on posts controller :

```
 def update
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])

   if @post.update(params[:post].permit(:title, :body, :published))
     redirect_to @post
   else
     render 'edit'
   end
 end
```

Comment: Do you want the checkbox to self-submit (like a button) and publish right away, or submit with the rest of a form?

Comment: Do you mean `Post.where(published: true)` as query or do you mean the checkbox helper?

Comment: @JacobVanus
I want check the check_box first before click submit button. It's should be `False` by default. Thank you!

Comment: @SebastiánPalma
Yes, as a query.

Thank you!

Comment: To make it false as default you can set the default value on the migration as false, and/or in the checkbox too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a published boolean column on your `posts` table with a migration

```
rails g migration add_published_to_posts published:boolean
```

Then, on the migration file generated, set `default: false` for published column

```
class AddPublishedToPosts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :posts, :published, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

So each time a new blog post is created will be have `published` as `false`. You can set this column to `true` with a checkbox on the form you use to edit the blog post.

Then on your model you can define a scope to pull published blogs based on this flag

```
# app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :published, -> { where(published: true) }
  scope :unpublished, -> { where(published: false) }
end
```

You can use this scope to pull published blog posts on your view with `Post.published` and unpublished blog posts with `Post.unpublished`

Comment: Thanks @sa77
I follow your code, but now my all my posts are hidden/not showing on index page. Is this the correct way to render the checkbox form : `<%= f.check_box :published %>`? Because it's seems not working, even thou I checked `Published`, it's still not showing. How I can filter on controller, rather on on view?

Comment: yes.. check your `posts_controller.rb`.. you must add `:published` as permitted strong parameter to allow updating it on form submit

Comment: Great! I forgot that part. Thank you, you are awesome! @sa77